# Increasing scalability of lagom service

Tags: akka, akka-http, lagom

I am new to Lagom. Created a hello world microservice using Lagom. The service-impl  does not have any dependency on any kind of db or logic, Just returning a hardcoded string.

But when I am trying to do a load testing on the service, it slows down, only able to support 4 request at a time. I have not provided any configuration. 
Any help ?

Comment: In developement environment or in production environment (built and deployed)?

Comment: developement environment

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend doing load testing with Lagom Production-Mode. We have a Lagom service with very simple logic, that response less than 1 ms and without problem process 1K rps on one node.

Comment: can u comment on how to do it?

Comment: @NabarunDey You can use [Lightbend Orchestration](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/lightbend-orchestration/current/index.html) for example. But Lagom 1.5 doesn't support it (see [Migration Guide](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/latest/scala/Migration15.html#Lightbend-Orchestration))